# WPF MVVM: Access DataGridTextColumn Cells

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datagridtextcolumn

I have a dynamically DataGrid generated from a DataGridTextColumn collection.
Is there any way to access the cells of the column directly from the DataGridTextColumn object?

Thanks!

Comment: Cells live in (or, children of) a row, not the column. Why do you need to access the cells in MVVM scenario?

Comment: I want to change cells appearance based on data that comes from the DB, the specific data is retrieved by the cell's column header and row header.

Comment: The controls, in MVVM scenario, are not supposed to access DB - that's what View Model/Model are for. For what it's worth, I'd do this: get the data to view model, do your calculations and set a property on data of each cell. Then use a trigger/converter in style for cell (`DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle`) or in the data template of the cell (`DataGridTextColumn.CellTemplate`/`DataGridTextColumn.EditCellTemplate`).